# Create copy of an Array and retain it when the original Array change

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have this array arr_original and copy the values of arr_titles. When i change the value of the arr_title the arr_original is also change. I want to copy the values of arr_title into arr_original but dont change the value of arr_original when i change the value of arr_tile. heres my code:

```
NSMutableArray *arr_original = [NSMutableArray new];

NSMutableArray *arr_title = [singletonManager.dictionaryAttribute objectForKey:attributeTitle];
//values of array {'one','two','three'}

[arr_original addObjectsFromArray:arr_title];
//copy values of arr_title
//values of array  arr_original{'one','two','three'}

[arr_title replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"five"];
//replace value
//values of array  arr_title{'five','two','three'}

//values of array  arr_original{'five','two','three'}
```

I just want the value of arr_original to be retain and not be change even i change the arr_title value. Help Pls thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *arr_original = [NSMutableArray new];

NSMutableArray *arr_title = [singletonManager.dictionaryAttribute objectForKey:attributeTitle];
for (id obj in arr_title){
[arr_original addObject:[[arr_title objectAtIndex:[arr_title indexOfObject:obj]] copy]]; //Copy the item
}


[arr_title replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"five"];
```

This would resolve your problem

Comment: If you need more explanation on my code I would need you to put on your logic here

Comment: Instead of for loop why don't you just use: `[arr_original addObjectsFromArray:[arr_title copy]];`?

Comment: You need to iterate each object and copy it. if you do `[arr_title copy]` you wont be iterating you will only copying arr_title array. Which is wrong

Comment: @iDev. [NSArray copy] method will do one-level-deep copy and will call copyWithZone for each NSString. In this case it is enough.

Comment: `[NSArray copy]` wont do deep copy

Comment: Sorry. I read documentation more carrefourly and you are right. copy won't do deep copy. `[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldArray copyItems:YES]` does.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this,

```
[arr_original addObjectsFromArray:arr_title];
```

try this,

```
arr_original = [arr_title copy];
```

That simple is that!

Answer (score 1):

The code you have given does not have the result you show in your comments. Look for a problem in how you are logging or interpreting what is happening.